# codeigniter checkbox array handling issue

Tags: arrays, forms, codeigniter, checkbox

I have form fields which are checkboxes as below :

```
<input id="abirrules@gmail.com" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="abirrules@gmail.com" style="float:left;border:2px dotted #00f" name="email[]">
<input id="abirrules1@gmail.com" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="abirrules1@gmail.com" style="float:left;border:2px dotted #00f" name="email[]">
<input id="abirrules3@gmail.com" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="abirrules3@gmail.com" style="float:left;border:2px dotted #00f" name="email[]">
```

But when in the controller I am taking a **var_dump($this->input->post('email'))** , it displays **bool(false)** .

in the controller I have this method :

```
public function referral_email()
{
    $data = $this->input->post('email');
    var_dump($data);exit;
 }
```

How to access this array of checkboxes in my controller ?

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: I have updated just now @Colin

Comment: How/Where are you loading your view?

Comment: I am loading my view from a different controller . And the form data is getting submitted to this controller.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but your id="" attribute probably shouldn't have an '@' character in it.

Comment: what's your form submitting url?

Comment: @debaShish: Please post your other controller's code as well

Comment: @minboost...no buddy...it didn't help

Comment: @user973254 , my form submitting url is http://localhost/<controller_name>/referral_email

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` and see what's there in raw, also you don't need `exit`

Comment: What's version of CodeIgniter? It is no problem on 2.0.3 version. Please show your views completely.

Comment: @debaShish are other values passing to the controller? can you show your form?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem where when I get back to the controller.  All values are passing except for the checkbox arrays :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by any chance trying to trim the output using the form validation library? I had the same problem, and removing 'trim' from the validation rules solved it.

Comment: Bingo @Talha...that was exactly what I was doing...thanks for the solution buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the form tag surrounding the text boxes has the attribute method="post" or else it might be submitting to the $_GET array. I got it to work with the following code:

Controller

```
public function referral_email()
{
    $data = $this->input->post('email');
    var_dump($data);
}
```

View

```
<form method="post" action="welcome/referral_email">
<input id="abirrules@gmail.com" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="abirrules@gmail.com" style="float:left;border:2px dotted #00f" name="email[]">
<input id="abirrules1@gmail.com" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="abirrules1@gmail.com" style="float:left;border:2px dotted #00f" name="email[]">
<input id="abirrules3@gmail.com" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="abirrules3@gmail.com" style="float:left;border:2px dotted #00f" name="email[]">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` works on strings, but your `$_POST['email']` is an array.  The correct fix should be to pass the field name as `'email[]'` when using the form validation library (in the code you didn't show us but commented on later).

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields